# How do I associate enum value with a class?

Tags: java, enums

I'm building a network request util using enum but I can't figure out how to parameterize it:

```
public enum Request {
    ENDPOINT_1 (FOO.class, "https://bar.com/foo");
    ENDPOINT_2 (BAR.class, "https://bar.com/bar");

    // How can I make Class<?> a template parameter here?
    private final Class<?> className;
    private final String url;
    Endpoint(Class<Class> className, String url) {
        this.className = className;
        this.url = url;
    }

    // and here?
    Class<?> sendHttpRequest() {
       // Will return an object of type this.className
    }
}
```

There's somewhat [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731024/java-enum-association) question for enums but I want it to work for class.

Comment: pretty sure you can just `Endpoint(Class<?> className, String url)`