# enums vs. classes: code duplication, composition, extension, generics

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, composition, code-duplication

> Note: I realize that this is very similar to the question [eliminating
>   duplicate Enum code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213/eliminating-duplicate-enum-code), but I think it may be useful to discuss this
>   separately since I'm also mentioning issues like extension
>   (sublclassing) and generics. I apologize if this seems redundant.

I'm implementing some optimizations in a program that I wrote a while ago. The current one attempts to eliminate code duplication that occurred as a result of the lack of support for abstract enums in Java (...and of sub-optimal design, I'll admit it).

Here's a simplified version of the current problem.
There's an interface `IConfigResourceDescriptor` that provides the necessary information to load some XMLs into certain classes (which implement `IResourceRoot`):

```java
public interface IConfigResourceDescriptor {
    String getResourceName();
    String getResourceLocation();
    <T extends IResourceRoot> Class<T> getRootClass();
    IConfigType getConfigType();
    ...
}
```

I have different sets of configurations that can be defined by different applications or different parts of the same application depending on what is required there.
For example here I show 2 sets, `ResourceDescriptorA` and `ResourceDescriptorB`, such that one is more oriented towards the business logic (`ResourceDescriptorA`) and the other towards the user interface (`ResourceDescriptorB`). As you can see their code is identical; the only reason they're separate is that it makes sense to keep these 2 sets of configurations independent from each other, but from the point of view of their implementation they're exactly the same.

```java
public enum ResourceDescriptorA implements IConfigResourceDescriptor {
    MODEL("model.xml", "config/", Model.class, ConfigTypeA.MODEL),
    RULES("rules.xml", "config/validation/", Rules.class, ConfigTypeA.RULES),
    HELP("help.xml", "config/", Help.class, ConfigTypeA.HELP);

    private String resourceName;
    private String resourceLocation;
    private Class<? extends IResourceRoot> rootClass;
    private IConfigType configType;

    private <T extends IResourceRoot> ResourceDescriptorA(String resourceName,
       String resourceLocation, Class<T> rootClass, IConfigType configType) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.resourceLocation = resourceLocation;
        this.rootClass = rootClass;
        this.configType = configType;
    }

    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }
    public String getResourceLocation() {
        return resourceLocation;
    }
    public <T extends IResourceRoot> Class<T> getRootClass() {
        return rootClass;
    }
    public IConfigType getConfigType() {
        return configType;
    }
    ...
}
```

```java
public enum ResourceDescriptorB implements IConfigResourceDescriptor {
    DIALOGS("dialogs.xml", "config/", Dialogs.class, ConfigTypeB.DIALOGS),
    FORMS("forms.xml", "config/", Forms.class, ConfigTypeB.FORMS),
    MENUS("menus.xml", "config/", Menus.class, ConfigTypeB.MENUS);

    private String resourceName;
    private String resourceLocation;
    private Class<? extends IResourceRoot> rootClass;
    private IConfigType configType;

    private <T extends IResourceRoot> ResourceDescriptorB(String resourceName,
       String resourceLocation, Class<T> rootClass, IConfigType configType) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.resourceLocation = resourceLocation;
        this.rootClass = rootClass;
        this.configType = configType;
    }

    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }
    public String getResourceLocation() {
        return resourceLocation;
    }
    public <T extends IResourceRoot> Class<T> getRootClass() {
        return rootClass;
    }
    public IConfigType getConfigType() {
        return configType;
    }
    ...
}
```

### Solution

My idea is to move the code to a helper class and reference that from the enums.
Also, to avoid having lots of methods that just wrap invocations to the actual `IConfigResourceDescriptor` (the helper class), I've defined a new interface `IConfigResourceDescriptorProvider` which simply returns the `IConfigResourceDescriptor`, which then can be used to get the actual description of the configuration.
The enums now implement `IConfigResourceDescriptorProvider` rather than `IConfigResourceDescriptor`.

New helper class which contains the actual implementation:

```java
public class ConfigResourceDescriptor implements IConfigResourceDescriptor {

    private String resourceName;
    private String resourceLocation;
    private Class<? extends IResourceRoot> rootClass;
    private IConfigType configType;

    public <T extends IResourceRoot> ConfigResourceDescriptor(String resourceName,
       String resourceLocation, Class<T> rootClass, IConfigType configType) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.resourceLocation = resourceLocation;
        this.rootClass = rootClass;
        this.configType = configType;
    }

    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }
    public String getResourceLocation() {
        return resourceLocation;
    }
    public <T extends IResourceRoot> Class<T> getRootClass() {
        return rootClass;
    }
    public IConfigType getConfigType() {
        return configType;
    }
    ...
}
```

New interface implemented by the enums. It simply returns the actual descriptor:

```java
public interface IConfigResourceDescriptorProvider {
    IConfigResourceDescriptor getResourceDescriptor();
}
```

The enums are simplified: the constructor creates a `ConfigResourceDescriptor` (helper class) using the values of the parameters. The `ConfigResourceDescriptor` is the actual descriptor.

```java
public enum ResourceDescriptorProviderA implements IConfigResourceDescriptorProvider {
    MODEL("model.xml", "config/", Model.class, ConfigTypeA.MODEL),
    RULES("rules.xml", "config/validation/", Rules.class, ConfigTypeA.RULES),
    HELP("help.xml", "config/", Help.class, ConfigTypeA.HELP);

    private IConfigResourceDescriptor resourceDescriptor;

    private <T extends IResourceRoot> ResourceDescriptorA(String resourceName,
       String resourceLocation, Class<T> rootClass, IConfigType configType) {
        resourceDescriptor = new ConfigResourceDescriptor(resourceName,
                  resourceLocation, rootClass, configType);
    }

    public IConfigResourceDescriptor getResourceDescriptor() {
        return resourceDescriptor;
    }
}
```

```java
public enum ResourceDescriptorProviderB implements IConfigResourceDescriptorProvider {
    DIALOGS("dialogs.xml", "config/", Dialogs.class, ConfigTypeB.DIALOGS),
    FORMS("forms.xml", "config/", Forms.class, ConfigTypeB.FORMS),
    MENUS("menus.xml", "config/", Menus.class, ConfigTypeB.MENUS);

    private IConfigResourceDescriptor resourceDescriptor;

    private <T extends IResourceRoot> ResourceDescriptorB(String resourceName,
       String resourceLocation, Class<T> rootClass, IConfigType configType) {
        resourceDescriptor = new ConfigResourceDescriptor(resourceName,
                  resourceLocation, rootClass, configType);
    }

    public IConfigResourceDescriptor getResourceDescriptor() {
        return resourceDescriptor;
    }
}
```

The fact that `ConfigResourceDescriptor` is a class and not an enum also means it can be extended to provide extra functionality. Maybe then I'll have a `ResourceDescriptorProviderC` that instantiates `AdvancedConfigResourceDescriptor` instead of `ConfigResourceDescriptor` and will be able to provide more functionality:

```java
public class AdvancedConfigResourceDescriptor extends ConfigResourceDescriptor {
    // additional methods
}
```

The fact that now the enumerations do not implement `IConfigResourceDescriptor` but rather `IConfigResourceDescriptorProvider` means that where I used to do...

```java
ResourceDescriptorProviderA.MODEL.getResourceName();
```

...now I have to do...

```java
ResourceDescriptorProviderA.MODEL.getResourceDescriptor().getResourceName();
```

...but the use of resource descriptors is very centralized in my code and I only need to make a few changes. I like this better than having to define *all* the wrapper methods in *all* the enums that implement the interface.
I don't have any external contract so I won't break any client by changing this.

### And the question is...

Is this ok or is there anything I'm not anticipating that could be problematic? Do you see any big (or small, or medium) no-nos in this approach? Is there a better approach?

This is something that has come up repeatedly and I'm never sure what the correct approach is.
I tried to look for good and bad practices concerning the use of enums but (surprisingly enough) I only found very basic stuff or examples that are too specific to be of use for me. If you can recommend good articles/blogs/books that I could read on the subject I would also appreciate it.
Thank you!

---

### Generics

Another advantage of using a class instead of an enum is that I can make it (and the interface `IConfigResourceDescriptor`) generic:

```java
public interface IConfigResourceDescriptor<T extends IResourceRoot> {
    String getResourceName();
    String getResourceLocation();
    Class<T> getRootClass();
    IConfigType getConfigType();
    ...
}
```

```java
public class ConfigResourceDescriptor<T extends IResourceRoot> implements IConfigResourceDescriptor<T> {

    private String resourceName;
    private String resourceLocation;
    private Class<T> rootClass;
    private IConfigType configType;

    public ConfigResourceDescriptor(String resourceName,
       String resourceLocation, Class<T> rootClass, IConfigType configType) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.resourceLocation = resourceLocation;
        this.rootClass = rootClass;
        this.configType = configType;
    }

    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }
    public String getResourceLocation() {
        return resourceLocation;
    }
    public Class<T> getRootClass() {
        return rootClass;
    }
    public IConfigType getConfigType() {
        return configType;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see any problems with your approach. There is one potential future issue you may come across but it should be easily avoided.

The issue will arise when you wish to add functionality to your `enum`s. It may then be a little unnerving deal with the fact that the data attached to the `enum` is in a surrogate object while the functionality is in the `enum` especially if the functionality depends on the data.

I like your approach and intend to investigate its use for myself.

Meanwhile there are two other techniques you may like to experiment with.

One similar to yours but the `enum` is an inner-class of an object which inherits from a generic superclass whose generic type includes the `enum`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14773325/823393) is a post containing an example. The trick here is to pass an `EnumSet` of the enum to the parent constructor so it can provide common functionality.

The second technique may be of less interest to you because it actually involves making a proxy combination of an `enum` and another object. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114128/823393) is a recently posted example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I'll stick to my implementation but I quite like what you posted in your [first link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772855/making-a-code-using-enum-generic/14773325#14773325). I'll definitely keep that in mind if I run into that situation.
I'll wait a bit before marking this as the answer but it'll probably be the one :)
Thanks again!